# Create a hyperlink based on a field entry

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, hyperlink, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am trying to format a column and create a custom hyperlink in a column field based on a specific criteria.

I have three options for this field and I only want to create a link if the field is one specific option. My options are "Available, Not Available, and Limited".

I want SharePoint to create a link to another page when the option is set to "Limited" only.

[image]

The code I am working with is below:

```
{
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "='http://www.google.com/' + ''"
  }
```

I have tried setting the `href` to `"href": "=if(@currentField=='Limited' + 'http://www.google.com')"`

...and several other parameters but it keeps adding links to all fields in the column or just failing completely to add the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below JSON code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "=if(@currentField == 'Limited', 'http://www.google.com', '')"
      },
      "style": {
        "display": "=if(@currentField == 'Limited', 'block', 'none')"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "style": {
        "display": "=if(@currentField == 'Limited', 'none', 'block')"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Microsoft documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)